# How to record a google assistant demo?

Tags: voice, quicktime, google-assistant-sdk

I just built a voice conversational app that runs on google assistant. However, I am not able to figure out how to record a demo of this app for sharing with other people. I am using iPhone and Mac. Video recording part works just fine, but I am not able to record the voice conversation.

I tried QuickTime video recording with the phone as my video source. If I choose phone as the audio source it records what my app is saying, but it won't record what I am saying. If I choose my mac's microphone as the source it records what I saying (through the mac's mic), but it won't record what the app is saying (because the app audio is not coming through the any of the speakers anymore).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. The problem is that the Assistant is capturing the input from the microphone, so its blocking other apps from doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

2 Suggestions here which hopefully must resolve your problem:

1) Connect iPhone with Mac, open Quick Time Player, choose to record phone screen, with audio via Mac's microphone. Make sure iPhone's volume is max. Start recording. It must sort out the issue.

2) If not still, try out optimizing audio or overlap another fine tuned audio (separately recorded) on this recorded video. In nutshell, optimizing the video generated with voice over, if required.

Comment: Option-1 does not work. When the iphone is plugged into the mac, it stops outputting audio to its speakers.